# jquery not working with css media queries

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, if-statement, media-queries

I have an element called ".left". Its css looks like this:

```
.left{
  float:right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;}
```

I have a media query for this element that looks like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 570px) {
    .left{
      display: none;}
 }
```

What I'm trying to do is have a button named ".close" change it's function when the media query is activated. I want one,two,three to fadein if display:none and one,two,three,four to fadein if display does not = none. This is what I have so far in jquery:

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function($) {
        console.log( "ready!" );

        $(".close").on('click',function() {
            if ($(".left").css("display") == "none" ){
                $("#one,#two,#three").fadeIn();}
            else {
                $("#one,#two,#three,#four").fadeIn();}
        });
    });
</script>
```

However, what I've coded only executes the if condition and not the else condition... no matter what size the browser is.

I need some help! Thanks!

Comment: Your solution should work unless the media query CSS is not being set or you have multiple elements with class `.left`. Check whether CSS is being set or not. also make sure that `$('.left')` is targeting the correct selector.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar: Thanks for your response. The media query CSS is being set, because as I resize the window, .left disappears when it should. It is the only element with that class.

Comment: can you share the link

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/N7jEB/1/ It seems to be working on here with my simplified code, but not with my more complicated code.

Comment: works fine here. http://jsfiddle.net/9zVL8/ . resize output window and see the result.

Comment: Ok, I found out what was going wrong. Basically, whenever I had ".close" appear, .four would .fadeOut. So the jquery performed the :hidden function no matter the screen size.

Comment: My issue now is that once the jquery performs the function, the media query ceases to work because query adds inline "display:block" to fadeIn elements. SO the "display:none" in the jquery is overridden after the first time I click close.

Comment: Ok I fixed it by adding: $(".left").css('display', '');

Comment: but that would set value to empty right??

Comment: @MilindAnantwar Only on the inline code, not on CSS stylesheet!

Comment: nm. you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try

[:hidden Selector](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/)

[.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    console.log("ready!");
    $(".close").on('click', function () {
        if ($(".left").is(":hidden")) { //check if .left is hidden or not
            $("#one,#two,#three").fadeIn();
        } else {
            $("#one,#two,#three,#four").fadeIn();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work either for some reason! When the window is larger than the media query, the #four still fades out.

Comment: It did work! As did my own function! Read above. Super complicated and annoying. JQUERY WILL BE THE DEATH OF ME LOL

Answer (score 0):

You should be using media queries in javascript. See here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia

```
$( document ).ready(function($) {
    console.log( "ready!" );

    $(".close").on('click',function() {

      if(window.matchMedia("(max-width: 570px)").matches) {
        $("#one,#two,#three").fadeIn();}
      } else {
        $("#one,#two,#three,#four").fadeIn();}
      }

    });
});
```